# how to fetch image path from database using byte array in android

Tags: android

**W/System.err(15366): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1**

```
byte[] bytes = cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex(imgarr.get(i)));          
ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);                
Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Cursor has only one row, but you are trying to access 2nd row of the Cursor.

Add the below line

```
cur.moveToFirst()
```

just before getBlob function